# KeyDown and Cocoa Sample

Tags: cocoa, osx-leopard

I'm learning how to build programs with Cocoa. I'm using a sample Apple application that records video from a webcam. I'd like to start and stop the video by capturing the key press. I've tried to override the keydown event but I've read that it's not possible in an `NSObject`. How can I handle this kind of event?

The class of application extends a `NSObject` class.

This is the code:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
  NSLog(@"Hi there");
  NSString *characters = [event characters];
  if ([characters length]) {
    switch ([characters characterAtIndex:0]) {
      case NSUpArrowFunctionKey:
      NSLog(@"Key UP");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've tried to override Keydown event but I've read that It's not possible in an NSObject.

Correct. Only a responder can respond to events.

> How can I handle this kind of event?

Implement a responder. Subclassing NSWindow or NSWindowController will work. Make sure you make your actual window or window controller an instance of your subclass.

The Cocoa documentation explains further.

> The class of application extends a NSObject class.

Why? Normally, the principal class of the application bundle is NSApplication or a subclass of that—and there aren't many good reasons to subclass NSApplication.

> PS: What's a very good book to start learn MacOS Programming?

I didn't learn by the Hillegass book, myself (I stuck to Apple's docs), but it's a very popular recommendation and I have read it and can tell you it's good.

Comment: Be careful that the window controller, if present, is the last responder for events messages. The delegates only get action messages, not event messages.

Comment: Good catch. I'll edit my answer to not claim that being the window delegate will work.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide - The Responder Chain](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2):

> The responder chain is a linked series of responder objects to which an event or action message is applied. When a given responder object doesn’t handle a particular message, the object passes the message to its successor in the chain (that is, its next responder).

When you press a key the window receives the keyDown event. Then it dispatches the event to the *first responder*, that usually is the control with a blue bezel around its border (try to click on the address field in Safari or Firefox, when it's blue-bezeled then it has first-responder status).

If the first responder does not *eat* the keypress (the Safari address field does eat it when it displays a character) then it passes it down the *responder chain* to the *next responder* in the view hierarchy, then to the window and to the window controller as you can see in the [Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2). (Take care that the action responder is another story.)

So you have to implement the keyDown: on a view of your window or in the window itself, if it has no views that eat events. The simplest way to test is to override the keyDown: method of an empty window

To put your hands into the inner workings you can even try overriding the sendEvent: method of a window. sendEvent: dispatches the events to the views of the window, and from there you can for example log all the events managed by the window.

Answer (score 4):

> Subclassing NSWindow or
>   NSWindowController will work.

Similarly, you can subclass NSView and override its event-handling methods.

> What's a very good book to start learn
>   MacOS Programming?

[Learn Objective-C on the Mac](http://books.google.com/books?id=zhGJnXQNvmsC&dq=Learn+objective+c+on+the+mac+MARK+DALRYMPLE&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=-D3l4JpAgd&sig=YgqCDAWQrehBR6G0owHjyQE5QnI&hl=en&ei=4oEbS5HQLI-YMavhmfMC&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by Dalrymple is really straightforward, covers enough basics and moves fast enough to get you off the ground in a short bit. It touches on everything from Xcode and Interface Builder to OOP and Objective-C practices. Particularly helpful to beginners (IMHO) are the source file organization and Foundation kit chapters.

Best of luck!

Comment: "Make sure you make your actual window or window controller an instance of your subclass." Another thanks to Peter. This helped on another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854112/keyup-event-heard-overridden-nsview-method