# detecting keyboard events in cocoa, specifically the Return/Tab keys

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm messing around with the Cocoa text system, and right now, all I need to be able to do is detect when the user presses either the Tab or Return key.

Not sure if this makes a difference, but I built a text editor from scratch programmatically, so I only have a reference to the NSTextStorage object, as everything else has been released.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
And I apologize for the noobile question.

Comment: If you built a text editor from scratch, how did you handle all the other keyboard input?

Comment: I would seriously question the wisdom of creating a text editor from scratch if you can't answer this yourself. `NSTextView` and related classes provide an *extremely* dense, complex and full-featured text handling system that has been built over many years by experts. It is very, very unlikely that you can improve upon it if you're starting from scratch. For the sake of your users, *please* just use `NSTextView` and its related classes to do what you want. If there is a reason that you feel it won't work, just ask and someone here will be able to help.

Comment: I have 8 NSTextContainers with corresponding NSTextViews. That's the only reason I didn't just use an NSTextView from the IB.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)keyDown: (NSEvent *) event {

   if ([event keyCode] == 13){ //For return key

   }
   if ([event keyCode] == 9){ //For tab key

   }

}
```

This method is to be overridden and will be called when ever a key is pressed.

Comment: The keyCodes are extremely helpful, thank you. Though I can't seem to get the method working. Do I need to do anything about appending text to the nstextstorage object? Or anything else? I'm pretty lost right now.

Comment: Yeah, should of read your question more carefully: You need an appropriate class try sub-classing `NSWindow`or `NSWindowController`.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143843/keydown-and-cocoa-sample